# $\pi$-separable group and its homomorphic image

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Show that every subgroup and every homomorphic image of a $\pi $-separable group $G$ is also $\pi $-separable. I find a normal series of a subgroup or homomorphic image but I can not show that every quotient group is $\pi $ or $\pi '$ group.

Answer (score 2):

Le $N/M$ be a quotient of the normal series of your group $G$ with factors that are either $\pi$- or $\pi'$-groups.

Consider first the case of subgroups.

If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, the induced factor in the series for $H$ will be
$$
\frac{H \cap N}{H \cap M}
=
\frac{H \cap N}{(H \cap N) \cap M}
\cong 
\frac{(H \cap N)M}{M}
\le
\frac{N}{M}.
$$
So $\dfrac{H \cap N}{H \cap M}$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $N/M$.

For quotients, let $K$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. The induced factor in the series for $G/K$ will be
$$
\frac{N K}{M K} 
=
\frac{N (M K)}{MK}
\cong
\frac{N}{N \cap M K}
\cong
\frac{N / M}{(N \cap M K)/M}.
$$
So $\dfrac{N K}{M K}$ is isomorphic to a quotient of $N/M$.

Comment: What about the homomorphic image of a π-separable group?

Comment: Same as quotients, via the first isomorphism theoren.